# SharpDX Not Drawing

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

I am trying my hand at writing a simple DirectX 11 application in C# using SharpDX. I am able to set the clear color, and that works, but when I try to draw polygons, they do not show up. I am creating a new `Game` class in  another source file to create the window and draw to it.

Game.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Drawing;

using SharpDX.Windows;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.Direct3D;
using SharpDX.D3DCompiler;
using SharpDX;

using DXMath = SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop;
using D3D11 = SharpDX.Direct3D11;

namespace testthing
{
    class Game : IDisposable
    {
        private RenderForm renderForm;
        private int width = 1280;
        private int height = 720;

        private D3D11.Device device;
        private D3D11.DeviceContext context;
        private SwapChain swapChain;

        private D3D11.RenderTargetView renderTarget;

        private DXMath.RawVector3[] verts;
        private D3D11.Buffer vertexBuffer;

        private D3D11.VertexShader vertShader;
        private D3D11.PixelShader pixelShader;

        private D3D11.InputElement[] inputElements = new D3D11.InputElement[]
        {
            new D3D11.InputElement("POSITION", 0, Format.R32G32B32_Float, 0)
        };
        private ShaderSignature inputSignature;
        private D3D11.InputLayout inputLayout;

        private DXMath.RawViewportF viewport;

        private double time = 0;
        public Game()
        {
            renderForm = new RenderForm("DxDemo");
            renderForm.ClientSize = new Size(width, height);
            renderForm.AllowUserResizing = false;

            InitDevice();

            verts = new DXMath.RawVector3[] { new DXMath.RawVector3(-0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f), new DXMath.RawVector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f), new DXMath.RawVector3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f) };
            vertexBuffer = D3D11.Buffer.Create<DXMath.RawVector3>(device, D3D11.BindFlags.VertexBuffer, verts);

            CompileShaders();

            RenderLoop.Run(renderForm, Render);
        }
        private void InitDevice()
        {
            ModeDescription backBufferDesc = new ModeDescription(width, height, new Rational(60,1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm);
            SwapChainDescription swapChainDesc = new SwapChainDescription()
            {
                ModeDescription = backBufferDesc,
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1,0),
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
                BufferCount = 1,
                OutputHandle = renderForm.Handle,
                IsWindowed = true
            };

            D3D11.Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, D3D11.DeviceCreationFlags.None, swapChainDesc, out device, out swapChain);
            context = device.ImmediateContext;

            using (D3D11.Texture2D backBuffer = swapChain.GetBackBuffer<D3D11.Texture2D>(0))
            {
                renderTarget = new D3D11.RenderTargetView(device, backBuffer);
            }
            context.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(renderTarget);

            viewport = new DXMath.RawViewportF()
            {
                X = 0,
                Y = 0,
                Width = width,
                Height = height
            };
            context.Rasterizer.SetViewport(viewport);
        }
        private void CompileShaders()
        {
            using (var vsBC = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("vertex.hlsl", "main", "vs_4_0", ShaderFlags.Debug))
            {
                inputSignature = ShaderSignature.GetInputSignature(vsBC);
                vertShader = new D3D11.VertexShader(device, vsBC);
            }
            using (var psBC = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("pixel.hlsl", "main", "ps_4_0", ShaderFlags.Debug))
            {
                pixelShader = new D3D11.PixelShader(device, psBC);
            }
            context.VertexShader.Set(vertShader);
            context.PixelShader.Set(pixelShader);

            inputLayout = new D3D11.InputLayout(device, inputSignature, inputElements);
            context.InputAssembler.InputLayout = inputLayout;
        }
        private void Render()
        {
            time = time + 0.01;
            context.ClearRenderTargetView(renderTarget, new DXMath.RawColor4(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f));

            context.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new D3D11.VertexBufferBinding(vertexBuffer, Utilities.SizeOf<DXMath.RawVector3>(), 0));
            context.Draw(verts.Count(), 0);

            swapChain.Present(1, PresentFlags.None);
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            inputLayout.Dispose();
            inputSignature.Dispose();

            vertexBuffer.Dispose();

            vertShader.Dispose();
            pixelShader.Dispose();

            renderTarget.Dispose();
            swapChain.Dispose();

            device.Dispose();
            context.Dispose();

            renderForm.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

vertex.hlsl:

```
float4 main(float4 position : POSITION) : SV_POSITION
{
    return position;
}
```

pixel.hlsl:

```
float4 main(float4 position : SV_POSITION) : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

**EDIT:** Turns out the render target view is not being bound, even though I am calling `context.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(renderTarget)`.

Comment: Use a graphics debugger like https://renderdoc.org/builds

Comment: Are you not able to show triangle/polygon or directx window?

Comment: The window is working just fine,  the triangle isn't drawing.

Comment: @xoofx I ran my program through RenderDoc. I was not able to find why the triangle is not drawing. It shows up in the Vertex Shader input and output just fine. However, nothing is showing up in the GS/DS Output. Should I be concerned or is this just because I am not utilizing a feature?

Comment: @xoofx My bad! I've never used RenderDoc before so I was a bit confused. DirectX warns that there is not a render target view bound to slot 0, even though I called `context.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(renderTarget)`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I just did not know that viewports can't have a max depth more than 1.0 and I had to set the raster state to disable backface culling.